# Force mysql-php to throw a transaction error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, transactions

I am using php-codeigniter. I have created one transactional code. I want to check whether my transaction-error handling code works or not, hence I want to deliberately throw a transactional error in the second query($addNewQuery). Is it possible? How can I do this?

```
$this->db->trans_start();
        if($m_arrPostValues['replaceFlag'] == true) {
            $this->_deleteAllCategoryFromProduct($m_arrPostValues['categoryId']);
        }
        $addNewQuery = "
        insert into t_productcategory(a_categoryid,a_productid,a_createddate,a_createdby)
        select ".$m_arrPostValues['categoryId'].",?,now(),?
        from dual
        where not exists (select a_categoryproductid from t_productcategory where a_categoryid= ".$m_arrPostValues['categoryId']." and a_productid = ?)";
        foreach($m_arrPostValues['arrIds'] as $product) {
            $this->db->query($addNewQuery,array($product,$user,$product));
        }
        $this->db->trans_complete();

        if($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
            echo 'Transaction Error';exit;
        }
```

Comment: so what it will not show you any error?

Comment: if error occurs it will be handled by  `if($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)`